# How can I change out how a gem uses ActionMailer and substitute a different mailer class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, actionmailer

I am using a gem (Devise) that relies on the ActionMailer:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb#L5-15

I want it to use PostageApp:Mailer instead of ActionMailer.  But we don't know how to make that change since it is inside of a gem.  We don't want to break the gem so is there a way to make the change from within our app by using a library?

Answer (score 1):

I had to override the whole mailer class: http://help.postageapp.com/discussions/support/176-how-can-i-make-the-devisemailer-a-subclass-of-postageapp

Comment: ohh so you got it working?  Where did you create the class and how did you call it in config/devise?

Comment: I got it working under Rails 2.3.11 . I'm migrating my whole app to Rails 3.0.7 . I'll update with the results soon

Answer (score 0):

This person believes that all you may need to do is implement the same methods as ActionMailer, and it may work:
http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/e048dd5d9a0d1d5f/70f02d5bd67f1271

More here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb#L5-15

Comment: shouldn't I copy the entire controller not just those lines?

Comment: You should only need to copy the actions that are required to make PostageApp work like ActionMailer. See duck typing (if it looks, and walks, and talks like a duck, then it may as well be a duck): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: I see...but what if the app/devise needs the other methods found in the devise mailer?

Comment: I looked through everything, I think I am still puzzled...why wouldn't it still need the private methods...am I substituting out this mailer for Devise::Mailer?

Comment: I am confused about this too, any news?

Comment: Nope. I was just posting the reference link, in case it was useful. If this isn't getting you what you need, I could delete my answer. This was just my best guess at what you could do.